# Tengo un formulario en HTML que la información se envia al correo pero me llega en blanco

Tags: html, formularios, email, google-apps-script

Tengo un formulario en html que al hacer clic al botón de enviar deberia llegarme al correo electrónico la información del formulario, en efecto al llenar el formulario me llega el correo pero llega en blanco no se porque no envia la informacion que se esta llenando en el formulario, actualmente estoy usando el primer paso de la guía que está en https://github.com/dwyl/html-form-send-email-via-google-script-without-server que consegui en google q funciona para enviar la información del formulario usando google scripts, pero no se q tiene mi codigo que no envia con la información del formulario me llega en blanco el correo

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Registro para Manual de Aguas Residuales</title>
  <script src="https://s.codepen.io/assets/libs/modernizr.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


  
  <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.0/css/bootstrapValidator.min.css'>

      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

  
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">

    <form action="https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbw18YzPncG2P-Mfft02p4kmXpR6vSFtOYYKjfIOby5wTo4ok6KJ/exec" class="well form-horizontal" id="contact_form" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
<fieldset>

<!-- Form Name -->
<b><center><legend>Registro para Manual de Aguas Residuales</legend></center></b>

<!-- Text input-->

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Nombre</label>  
  <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
  <div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
  <input  name="first_name" placeholder="Nombre Completo" class="form-control"  type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Text input-->

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" >Apellidos</label> 
    <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
    <div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
  <input name="last_name" placeholder="Apellido Completo" class="form-control"  type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Text input-->
       <div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Correo Electrónico</label>  
    <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i></span>
  <input name="email" placeholder="Correo @ Electronico" class="form-control"  type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<!-- Text input-->
       
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Teléfono</label>  
    <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></i></span>
  <input name="phone" placeholder="Fijo o Celular" class="form-control" type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Text input-->
      
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Empresa</label>  
    <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></span>
  <input name="address" placeholder="Empresa donde Trabaja" class="form-control" type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Text input-->
 

<!-- Select Basic -->
   
<div class="form-group"> 
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Segmento Laboral</label>
    <div class="col-md-4 selectContainer">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></i></span>
    <select name="state" class="form-control selectpicker" >
      <option value=" " >Selecciona Segmento Laboral</option>
      <option>Automotores</option>
      <option>Salud</option>
      <option >Restaurantes</option>
      <option >Hoteles</option>
      <option>Industriales</option>
      <option >Otros</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

<!-- Text input-->
<b><center>Haz Like A nuestra pagina de Facebook Para Continuar con el Registro</center></b>  
<center><div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/todoenaguaecu" data-width="200" data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-size="large" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div></center>

<!-- Button -->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label"></label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
<center>
    <button <input type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" value="Send"> Registrarse <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span></button>
</center>

<script>
    function cerrar() { 
        $("body").html('<div alignt="center"><h1>Gracias por registrarse para recibir el manual de aguas residuales, verificaremos sus datos y en breve le haremos envio</h1></div>'); //Marca nuevo contenido con un mensaje que se envio exitosamente

        setTimeout(function(){
            window.close();
        },3000); //Dejara un tiempo de 3 seg para que el usuario vea que se envio el formulario correctamente

    }
</script>

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/es_LA/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.9";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<!-- Success message -->
<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert" id="success_message">Registro Exitoso <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></i> Gracias por registrarse para recibir el manual de aguas residuales, verificaremos sus datos y en breve le haremos envio</div>
</fieldset>
</form>
</div>
    </div><!-- /.container -->

  <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-validator/0.4.5/js/bootstrapvalidator.min.js'></script>

    <script src="js/index.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: La página referida incluye instrucciones aparentemente completas. ¿Has seguido todos los pasos que ahí se indican?

Comment: Una versión muy similar de esta misma pregunta fue publicada también en inglés, a esto se le llma "publicación cruzada" o "cross-post" y este tipo de publicaciones en varios sitios de [se] no son bien vistas, me parece que incluso cuando es en sitios de diferentes idiomas a menos que se sean muy buenas preguntas y la traducción o adecuación sea también muy buena.

Comment: Enlace a la otra publicación: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44422673/1595451